# Ionic 2 www empty folder

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to test a sample Ionic2 app. I have started using `ionic start AppName --v2`.

Got the code in local with `src` folder. But the `www` folder is empty. When I do `ionic serve`, its opening the app in browser and throws the below error.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path\to\folder\www\index.html'.
```

`www` folder is not getting updated with the compiled code. Nor `build` folder is getting generated inside the `src` folder. I have typescript and other compilers installed as well.

Comment: Uninstalling ionic and installing it again worked. My previous version was also the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing ionic framework, and making sure your CI is updated.

It could also be a permission issue, have you tried using `sudo` ?

```
sudo ionic start AppName tabs --v2 --ts
```

also make sure you are at the root of your application when running

```
ionic server
```